# MYSQL - Select 4 random rows and transpose them into columns of insert statement

Tags: mysql, database, select, sql-insert, transpose

Data scheme:

```
create table level (
  id int auto_increment primary key,
  # ... other data which is not relevant
);

create table session (
  id int auto_increment primary key,
  lvlid1 int not null,
  lvlid2 int not null,
  lvlid3 int not null,
  lvlid4 int not null,
  ts timestamp not null default current_timestamp,
  foreign key(lvlid1) references level(id),
  foreign key(lvlid2) references level(id),
  foreign key(lvlid3) references level(id),
  foreign key(lvlid4) references level(id)
);
```

How do I select 4 random distinct ids from level table into (lvlid1, lvlid2, lvlid3, lvlid4) of session table?
More specifically I want to know if it possible to do something like this:

```
insert into session (lvlid1, lvlid2, lvlid3, lvlid4)
values(TRANSPOSE(select id from level order by rand() limit 4))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to use a pivot query with a dynamic row number variable to select four random IDs in separate columns.

```
SET @row_number = 0;

INSERT INTO session (lvlid1, lvlid2, lvlid3, lvlid4)
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN t2.rn = 1 THEN t2.id END),
       MAX(CASE WHEN t2.rn = 2 THEN t2.id END),
       MAX(CASE WHEN t2.rn = 3 THEN t2.id END),
       MAX(CASE WHEN t2.rn = 4 THEN t2.id END)
FROM
(
    SELECT t.id, (@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS rn
    FROM
    (
        SELECT id FROM lv_kb00_level ORDER BY RAND()
    ) AS t
) AS t2
```

Comment: Thanks! I got the idea. But you need to split innermost select into two to make it work. It's assigning row_number first and 4 random will not contain 1, 2, 3, 4 for sure as it is now. But I managed to make it work.

Comment: I gave it more thought and now I think yeah with one more select you can omit `order by t2.rn limit 4` at all or move just `limit 4` back to innermost select. I don't know which is better performancewise.

Comment: You don't need `LIMIT 4` at all actually.  The pivot takes care of selecting the first four random rows and placing them into separate columns.